# jOrgChart (why is the drag and drop feature only working once)

Tags: jquery, html, css

SO I have started using a plug-in called jOrgChart. It has a dragAndDrop feature thats really cool. Unfortunately it only works for the first time I drag and drop it. In the demo in the website it works every time. Also In my code, the original list looks like it is just deleted in the rendered code. I imagine this has something to do with it becuase its not deleted in on the website.

Here's a link to the website: 
[jOrgChart demo (with links on top to GitHub for code)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html)

Also I have never used jsfiddle before but if someone can explain a little how it works, I'll insert a preview of this

Here's a look at some simple code:

***HTML***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pathway Builder 3.0</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/basic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jOrgChart.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="org" style="display: none;">
        <li>
            Food
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Fruit
                    <ul>
                    <li>Apples</li>
                    <li>Oranges</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

***basic.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#org').jOrgChart({
        dragAndDrop : true
    });
});
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML.  I don't see a closing `</ul>` for the `<ul>` called `#org`.  You also have a broken `script` tag for jQueryUI on the same line as your jOrgChart.js includes.

Comment: Hey, this is true, I had a longer example with correct html but the feature still wasn't working after the first time dragging it. Ill edit the post.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with the code you posted.  You'll have to create a demo that shows your problem so we have something to troubleshoot.  Otherwise, this is all guessing.  http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: Clarify this sentence... I've read it ten times and it makes no sense to me.  _"Also In my code, the original list looks like it is just deleted in the rendered code. I imagine this has something to do with it becuase its not deleted in on the website."_

Comment: Hey thanks for the input Im not sure why it was deleting the the <ul id="org"> but when I changed the default "defaults, chartElement to 'div' instead of body, and added a blank div tag after the <ul id="org"> in the html it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you are putting your chart, it will effect this.  When it builds the chart, it actually clears whatever is in the supposed charts parent.  Try making a div labeled `ID="chart"` then putting the chart into *that* div. Let me know if you need help.